# EXTJS ViewPort: allow to overlap

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I'm using extjs 4.1 I have a viewport which I'm using to layout my application. I have a panel in the north region which is where I created my applications banner. It's a Panel which uses a loader and loads a JSP which contains my banner code. In the JSP page I have a link at the bottom of the panel which uses javascript and when the user hovers over it a menu opens up. The issue is when the menu opens it doesn't open past the bottom of the north panel in the viewport. Is there a way to allow the menu to open and overlap into the center panel of the viewport?

Comment: It would help if you posted some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to set `floating : true` when I create my button this allows the menu to open up beyond the north panel when using an Ext component.